# Chef Template : Using a nested object to generate a configuration file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-template

I would like to generate a config file from a `Chef` template. What is the correct syntax for achieving this in `Chef 13+`

I have a databag with the following sub keys:

```
"mykey1" : {
  "param1" : "mysubvalue1",
  "param2" : "mysubvalue2"
},
"mykey2" : {
  "param1" : "mysubvalue11",
  "param2" : "mysubvalue22"
},
```

Then in my recipe I use the template resource:

```
template 'mytemplate.erb'
  ...
  variables ({
     :keys => [mykey1, mykey2]
  })
end
```

Then in the template:

```
<% @keys.each_pair do |name, _object| %>
  ["#{name}"]
  param1 = "#{_object.param1}"  # will this work??
<% end %>
```

What is the correct way to reference the `param1` and `param2`

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get the data like that, it's a normal Ruby hash object. So you would use `_object["param1"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming here years later?  Try this:

```
<% @keys.each_pair do |name, _object| %>
["#{name}"]
<%   _object.each do |param, sub| -%>
  <%= param %> = "<%= sub %>"
<%   end # _object.each -%>
<% end   # keys.each -%>
```

let me know how it goes.